# React Native - accessing 'this' in Button onPress causes app to crash

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I started learning React Native a couple of days ago and I've been stuck on this seemingly easy problem.

I have a signup form and I'm just trying to log the value of the form to the console after a user presses Submit. The problem is that when I press the button, the app hangs for about a minute and then crashes. There are no errors or logs so I don't know why it crashes, although I do know it happens when I try to call "this" in the onPress function.

Here is a bare bones example of my issue:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <Button
            title="Submit"
            onPress={this.onPress}
          />
      </View>
    );
  }

  onPress = () => {
    console.log(this);
  }
}
```

Running this code and pressing the button causes my app to crash. However, changing the `console.log(this)` to `console.log('test')` prevents the app from crashing.

My two questions are:

- What is the proper way to get a reference to the Component "this" inside an onPress function?
- How can I see the logs/errors when my app crashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attempting to log `this` might lead to a huge amount of output, and is possibly even cyclical.  Why do you need to print the entire object?  Can you narrow it down.  Your onPress method is correctly bound to `this` using the Class Fields syntax.

Comment: Thank you. This actually solved my problem. In my original code I was trying to log the form to the console (I'm using tcomb-form-native) using `console.log(this._form)`. Changing it to `console.log(this._form.getValue())` made it work, for some reason. I am new to mobile development, and coming from web development, and in web dev I never had issues like these. Thanks again!

Comment: The principle is the same - dump too much stuff, particularly with cyclical references, and you'll cause things to crash.  Smartphones might be pretty much fully functional computers but they still have significantly less resources to work with.  Glad it helped though!